# unable to list collections in azure document db with mongodb protocol support

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am currently using Python3 (pymongo) to connect to an Azure Document DB with Mongo protocol support.

```
# reference to connection string
self.connection_string = "mongodb://<user>:<pw>@<location>:<port>/<database>?ssl=true"

# creates the connection (this is working)
self.mongo_client = MongoClient( self.connection_string )

# show databases and there collections
print(self.mongo_client.database_names())
for db_name in self.mongo_client.database_names():
    print(db_name,">",self.mongo_client[db_name].collection_names())
```

Running the above snippet of code lists the databases however the collections are not listed. Running this on a local mongo db works as expected.

I was originally trying to run a query on a known collection within the database however, I can't even seem to be able to do that. I have MongoChef connected and is working as expected (able to run querys).

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it looks like that the current version of the mongo protocol on document db does not support this and that is why it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Greener, the issue seems to be caused by `pymongo`, not `DocumentDB with MongoDB protocol`.

I tried to connect `DocumentDB with MongoDB protocol` using the third party tool `Robomongo` successfully, and I could see the collections as below.

[image]

As reference, here is a workaround way for listing collections in PyMongo via Database level command [`listCollections`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/#dbcmd.listCollections), please see below.

```
>>> mongo_client.command('listCollections')
{'ok': 1, '_t': 'ListCollectionsResponse', 'cursor': {'firstBatch': [{'options': {}, 'name': 'testCollection'}], 'ns': 'testdb.$cmd.listCollections', 'id': 0}}
```

Hope it helps.